# How to set dns configurations when installing spark-on-k8s-operator?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Just to be clear, I've already opened a [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1924) on spark-on-k8s-operator project repository. But I've decided to ask here also, in case someone already has been throught it.

I'm trying to use the spark-on-k8s-operator using a different `dnsConfig`  and `dnsPolicy`  due to some restrictions and limitations of k8s cluster that I'm using.

Something like this in `values.yaml` of helm chart:

```
dnsConfig:
          nameservers:
          - XXX.XX.X.XXX
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
```

This is necessary because, in my case, if I don't set `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet` for the pods in my cluster, it's not solving the dns `kubernetes.default.svc` used to initialize the webhook. The image below shows the error if I don't set dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet (it happens for both `init-webhook` and `clean-up-webhook`)

[image]

I need to use the webhook activated in order to some customizations in SparkApplication take effect (like also, configure `dnsConfig` and `dnsPolicy`) for driver and executors, otherwise, it will not take effect.

Thanks!

I've already tried to edit the webhook job after it be deployed using `kubectl replace -f webhook.yaml --force`. The file `webhook.yaml` was like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install, pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-weight: "50"
  creationTimestamp: "2024-03-02T14:27:44Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: spark
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: spark-operator
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v1beta2-1.3.8-3.1.1
    helm.sh/chart: spark-operator-1.1.27
  name: spark-spark-operator-webhook-init
  namespace: spark-operator
  resourceVersion: "8042824"
spec:
  backoffLimit: 6
  completionMode: NonIndexed
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  suspend: false
  template:
    metadata:
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /usr/bin/gencerts.sh
        - -n
        - spark-operator
        - -s
        - spark-spark-operator-webhook
        - -r
        - spark-spark-operator-webhook-certs
        - -p
        image: ghcr.io/googlecloudplatform/spark-operator:v1beta2-1.3.8-3.1.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: main
        resources: {}
        securityContext: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
        - XXX.XXX.X.X
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: spark-spark-operator
      serviceAccountName: spark-spark-operator
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

I've also tried to edit the generated deployment of spark-operator..but no success.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: `...restrictions and limitations of k8s cluster ` - what's the issue here?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know the excatly reason, but, the cluster is not using the configured dns it should be using, so it's not able to access external service (the need of configure `dnsConfig`) and also, the `dnsPolicy` is not able to access the services inside the cluster (honeslty, I don't know the reason). I know it should be fixed in cluster configurations, but I'm trying to found a workaround to solve this temporarily problem.